# GPA Calculator, How do I add values from list to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a GPA Calculator as a small project but I cant figure out how to add the value from the users input together. I'm using if and elif commands to designate a GPA number to each letter grade. But when I try to add up all of them together at the end to the variable "gtotal" it keeps saying 0. I don't know where im going wrong and would really appreciate the help.

```
            print ("GPA Calculator")

            gtotal = 0
            ctotal = 0

            grades = []
            for i in (range(6)):
                grades.append(input("Enter Grades in Order Here: "))
                if grades == "A":
                    gtotal += 4
                elif grades == "A-":
                    gtotal += 3.7
                elif grades == "B+":
                    gtotal += 3.3
                elif grades == "B":
                    gtotal += 3
                elif grades == "B-":
                    gtotal += 2.7
                elif grades == "C+":
                    gtotal += 2.3
                elif grades == "C":
                    gtotal += 2
                elif grades == "C-":
                    gtotal += 1.7

            print(gtotal)
```

Im expecting to see a gtotal with all of the integers that represent the users letter input added up together. But it keeps return 0 when I print(gtotal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to append the `grades`, so after 6 iterations, it will be a list of 6 values. Since you are adding the `gtotal` for every iteration, your code will work when you remove the `append` function.

**Code:**

```
print ("GPA Calculator")

gtotal = 0
ctotal = 0

grades = []
for i in (range(6)):
    grades = input("Enter Grades in Order Here: ")
    if grades == "A":
        gtotal += 4
    elif grades == "A-":
        gtotal += 3.7
    elif grades == "B+":
        gtotal += 3.3
    elif grades == "B":
        gtotal += 3
    elif grades == "B-":
        gtotal += 2.7
    elif grades == "C+":
        gtotal += 2.3
    elif grades == "C":
        gtotal += 2
    elif grades == "C-":
        gtotal += 1.7

print(gtotal)
```

**Output:**

```
GPA Calculator
24
Enter Grades in Order Here: A
Enter Grades in Order Here: A
Enter Grades in Order Here: A
Enter Grades in Order Here: A
Enter Grades in Order Here: A
Enter Grades in Order Here: A
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating if else loop, just use a dictionary. Here, I summed the grade corresponding to the letter grade and then divide it by the number of subject. As a result, you'll get the weighted grade point avg.

```
In [3]: def get_grade(grade_list):
            grade_dict = dict(zip(['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B-', 'C+', 'C-'],
                                  [4, 3.7, 3.3, 3, 2.7, 2.3, 2, 1.7]))
            return sum([grade_dict[i] for i in grade_list])/(len(grade_list))

In [4]: get_grade(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B+'])
Out[4]: 3.825
```